# Android: Constantly Update Map With Coordinates from Web Service

Tags: android, android-service

Hello I am writing an app that makes the use of coordinates from a webserver. I know how to retrieve the coordinates from the webservice, but once I get them how can I constantly display them on the map. Sort of like the Location Listener updates the point on the map when the location from the location manager changes. I want to constantly update the points I receive from the webservice. 
Is this done with a Service? If so how?

```
        public class GeoUpdateHandler implements LocationListener {  

        @Override  
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {  
            ...
                GeoPoint point = new GeoPoint(lat, lng);  
            createMarker();  
            mapController.animateTo(point); // mapController.setCenter(point);  
        }
```

UPDATED: Code for Createmarker

```
private void createMarker() {  
        GeoPoint p = mapView.getMapCenter();  
        OverlayItem overlayitem = new OverlayItem(p, "", "");  
        itemizedoverlay.addOverlay(overlayitem);  
        mapView.getOverlays().add(itemizedoverlay);  
    }
```

UPDATED: Code for getting coordinates from webservice...

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(".../android/serverFile.php");
        JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
        try {
            JSONArray postjson=new JSONArray();
            postjson.put(json);
            // Execute HTTP Post Request
            System.out.print(json);
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            // for JSON:
            if(response != null)
            {
                InputStream is = response.getEntity().getContent();
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                String line = null;
                try {
                    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                        sb.append(line + "\n");
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } finally {
                    try {
                        is.close();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                String jsonStr = sb.toString();
                JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);
                String longitudecord = jsonObj.getString("lon");
                String latitudecord = jsonObj.getString("lat");
```

}

UPDATE WITH TIMER:

```
public void startService(){
    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask(){
        @Override
        public void run() {
                 //Call the method that contacts the server and  
                 //adds the coordinates to a list. Get those values from the list.  
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://www.kre8tiveinspired.com/android/serverFile.php");
            JSONObject json = new JSONObject();

            try {
                // JSON data:
                JSONArray postjson=new JSONArray();
                postjson.put(json);
                // Execute HTTP Post Request
                System.out.print(json);
                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                // for JSON:
                if(response != null)
                {
                    InputStream is = response.getEntity().getContent();
                    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                    String line = null;
                    try {
                        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                            sb.append(line + "\n");
                        }
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } finally {
                        try {
                            is.close();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                    String jsonStr = sb.toString();
                    JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);
                    // grabbing the menu object 
                    String longitudecord = jsonObj.getString("lon");
                    String latitudecord = jsonObj.getString("lat");
                    latcord = latitudecord;
                    loncord = longitudecord;
                }

            }catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
                 Handler handler = new Handler();
                 handler.post(new Runnable(){  
                       public void run(){

                        double aDouble = Double.parseDouble(loncord);
                    double bDouble = Double.parseDouble(latcord);

                    int lat = (int) (aDouble * 1E6);  
                        int lng = (int) (bDouble * 1E6);  
                        GeoPoint point = new GeoPoint(lat, lng);  
                        createMarker();  
                        mapController.animateTo(point); // mapController.setCenter(point);
                            //add the overlays to the map
                            // and call invalidate for the mapview.
                             mapView.invalidate();

                       }
                 });
            }

    }, 0, 1000); // Here im calling the timer every 10 seconds
```

Comment: code for createMarker();

Comment: @Agarwal just updated the question with createMarker();'s code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well what you can do is to use a `timer` to populate the map. Basically, you can have one method which contacts the server, fetches the coordinates and adds them into an arraylist. Now this method can be called from inside the timer (which can run every few seconds, depending on your needs). Also, inside this timer class, you can re-populate the map. Some code for this:

```
timer=new Timer();  // Refresh map via timer task.
    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask(){
        @Override
        public void run() {
                 //Call the method that contacts the server and  
                 //adds the coordinates to a list. Get those values from the list.  
                 Handler handler = new Handler();
                 handler.post(new Runnable(){  
                       public void run(){
                            //add the overlays to the map
                            // and call invalidate for the mapview.
                       }
                 });
            }

    }, 0, 10000); // Here im calling the timer every 10 seconds
```

If you would want to look at an example project that uses this idea, head [here](https://github.com/Alok-Sharma/BargeTracker/blob/master/src/com/social/FullMap.java), and have a look at the timer inside `onResume()`. It uses another class called `FetchParse` that contacts the server and gets the updated list of coordinates.

Comment: Also, dont forget to clear all the overlays from the map before you re-populate them inside the timer.

Comment: Thanks this sounds Ideal. I updated my initial question. I pasted my code for reaching the strings from webservice only to check if it words. I can make a separate method in the future. But nothing is happening.  I even made a toast to pop up every 10 seconds before pasting the other code in. And I can't out why?

Comment: so the toast isnt popping up every 10 seconds? Did you put the toast inside the handler?

Comment: Are you sure `startService()` is called? Put a log statement as the first line inside `startService()` and check if it works.

Comment: Also, have a look at the link I posted.

Comment: I ran the log statement, and the log statement worked. Its something wrong with how I am running the createmarker();

now its giving me the statement in the log...

MapActivity Couldn't get connection factory client
Failed to find provider info for com.googl.settings

It was working before when I was getting the location from the actualdevice but now im getting that message.

Comment: If the log is working fine, why do you think something is wrong with `createmarker()`? And about that warning, I think you can safely ignore it. Should not be a problem.

Comment: Ok I went back and tried to go step by step, before displaying on map i want to display a toast to see if im at least getting my coordinates from server. My function that access the server is called `postData()`. and it throws JSON Exception, when i put it in the timer function. and run it it throws an error saying:

java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()

how can a fix this. I wanted to make a toast every 6 min to see if I was getting my coords right from the server

Comment: That error means that you are trying to do something related to the UI outside the `run()` method. Make sure that all code that has anything to do with the UI is inside the `run()` method.

Answer (score 0):

```
GeoPoint p = mapView.getProjection().fromPixels((int) event.getX(),(int) event.getY());
Drawable srcdrawable = getApplicationContext().getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.pin_blue);
CustomItemizedOverlay srcitemizedOverlay = new CustomItemizedOverlay(srcdrawable, getApplicationContext());
OverlayItem srcoverlayitem = new OverlayItem(p, "Hello!", "This is your Location.");
srcitemizedOverlay.addOverlay(srcoverlayitem);
mapView.getOverlays().clear();
mapView.getOverlays().add(srcitemizedOverlay);
```

try this code in create marker

Comment: Thanks for the code, I updated my code to show I read in from the webservice...At the end i have two strings longitudecord and latitude cord...How is the code you gave me going to constantly read these strings from the webservice? Like maybe every 6-10 seconds?